# How to check if service's server response contains proper data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, metaprogramming

I use services to communicate with server for requesting data and I keep them in another file so it looks like that (and it's easier to read through):

```
var app_services = angular.module('app.services', []) 
        .service('dataService1', dataService1)
        .service('dateService2', dataService2);


dataService1.$inject = ['http']; 

function dataService1($http) { 
    return $http.get('api/datas')
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(failCallback)
} 

dataService2.$inject = ['http'];
function DataService2($http) {
//... code goes here
}
```

Then I'm calling them from controller:

```
ServiceController.$inject = ['dataService1'];
function testServiceController(dataService) {
    return dataService.then(function(data) {
    };

}
```

Simple and obvious.

Anyways, I need every service's response  from server to have proper data structure and I need to handle it. I do it by calling services as objects of my factory where I check data structure of service's responses, so the code looks like this:

```
var app_services = angular.module('app.services', [])
    .factory('serviceFactory', serviceFactory)
    .service('dataService', getService);

getService.$inject = ['serviceFactory'];

function getService(serviceFactory) {
var request = new ServiceFactory('api/datas')
return request.get();
}

serviceFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

function serviceFactory($http) {

var serviceObject = function(address) {
    this.address = address;
};

serviceObject.prototype.get = function(){
    return $http.get(this.address)
    .then(this.getComplete)
    .catch(this.getFailed);
}; 

       serviceObject.prototype.getComplete = function (response) {
            var data = response.data;

            if ((data.error !== '0' || !data.msg.length > 0)) {
                if (data.error !== '') {
                    throw new Error();
                } else if (data.msg == '' || !data.msg.length > 0) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
            }
            else {
                return data;
            }

        };

        serviceObject.prototype.getFailed = function (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong!');
        };

     return serviceObject;     
}
```

**Is this a good solution? Or can I do it in another, better/proper way?** I do know that angular's method `.services('getService', getService)` will  be provided with an instance of the function.In other words `new getService`
but I don't know if nesting `var request = new ServiceFactory('/api/adress')` 
directly has any sense or does it make the code less readable (well, for me it is legible but I want to improve myself as a programmer so I need to consult some stuff :P).

PS. Of course the code looks a little bit different in original file, but after copy-pasting it lost it's original indentations.

Comment: I'd make a start with your indentation ;) Your code looks ok to me @leanansith, I could think of a few ways to tidy up your code though... for human reading purposes